# Latex: The table width is larger than text, and its label numbering starts from 2

Tags: tables

I have a table built in Latex, it's shown larger than the width of the text. Although I tried many solutions available online, but no one of them has worked with them. I think that is because the text in header cells (first row) cannot be broken, they are written in one line.
And even its labels starts from 2 instead of 1, for example,  **Table 2**.: Labels  instead of **Table 1**. : Labels.

Here is the code I am using and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\refstepcounter{table}
\caption{Example}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\hline
\textbf{No} & \textbf{One-text} & \textbf{One-text} & \textbf{One-or-text}  (4,3,4)& \textbf{one-or-text}  (8,4,2)& \textbf{One-or-text}   (4,3,2)& One-or-text (4,2,2)\\ \hline
1-          & 0.0028            & 0                 & 0                    & 0                    & 0                    & 0           \\
2-          & 0.0063            & 0                 & 0.0025               & 0.00018              & 0.0000893            & 0           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Removing the `\refstepcounter{table}` instruction will take care of the numbering issue.

Comment: the table width is answered by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: @Mico  Thank you so much ... that worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To fix the numbering issue, omit the instruction `\refstepcounter{table}`.
- As you've (re)discovered, the `l` column type does *not* allow automatic line breaking. To allow automatic line breaking in the 6 data columns, while simultaneously setting the overall width of the table to `\textwidth`, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` envirohment, as is shown in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 
    % allow line breaking, suppress full justfication

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%%\centering % <-- not needed
%%%%\refstepcounter{table} %<-- delete or comment out this instruction
\caption{Example}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{L} @{}}
\hline
\textbf{No} & \textbf{One-text} & \textbf{One-text} & \textbf{One-or-text} (4,3,4) & \textbf{one-or-text} (8,4,2) & \textbf{One-or-text} (4,3,2) & One-or-text (4,2,2)\\ 
\hline
1- & 0.0028 & 0 & 0      & 0       &           0 & 0 \\
2- & 0.0063 & 0 & 0.0025 & 0.00018 & 0.0000893   & 0 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much,  but could you please explain this line for me `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{L} @{}}` ?

Comment: @Gze - The `tabularx` environment, unlike the `tabular` environment, takes two [2] arguments: (i) the desired width (here: `\textwidth`), and (ii) the column definitions, here: `l *{6}{L}`, which means "1 column of type `l` and 6 columns of type `L`. (The `L` column type is defined in the preamble as a variant of the `X` column type that's provided by the `tabularx` package.) Finally, the `@{}` particles instruct LaTeX to suppress whitespace padding on the left-hand and right-hand edges of the table.